# Zammad API: Create ticket with tag

Tags: php, api, zammad

**For those who don't want to read the whole question:**
I'm looking for the index in the API-Request (Zammad) to set a tag while creating a ticket.

**Details:**
I'm using PHP to make an API-Request to my server where Zammad is installed. The following shows the data i sent via curl:

```
json_encode([
    "title" => $title,
    "group_id" => 2,
    "priority_id" => 2,
    "category" => 'Some Category',
    "state_id" => 1,
    "type" => "Some Type", 
    "customer" => $userID, 
    "article" => [
        "body" => $htmlBody,
        "type" => "note",
        "content_type" => "text/html",
    ],
    "tag_list" => [ // <-- The question is about this segment
        "The tag i want to add",
    ],
]);
```

After converting the data to JSON, im sending it via POST to *http://<myServerIP>/api/v1/tickets*

**What I've tried so far:**
I tried guessing the index of the tag at which i failed.
The first full example is shown above.

Secondly:

```
...
"tag_id" => 9, // I've check its the actual ID of the tag i want to add
```

And Finally:

```
...
"tag" => "The tag i want to add",
```

Needless to say that i didn't succeed. Sometimes i get an error id (im assuming its because the index doesn't exist [who would have thought that? :)]), sometimes i get nothing and Zammad just creates the ticket without the tag. What do i mean when i say sometimes? I refer my tries specified above.

**What I've also tried:**
Searching for some answer on the web. The thing that comes close to what i want is [this](https://github.com/zammad/zammad/issues/850). But i would rather create the ticket with the tag instead of making another request just to add the tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've looked inside the code, its written in ruby. The index is 'tags' and needs to be sperated by `,`.

Basicly:

```
json_encode([
    "title" => $title,
    "group_id" => 2,
    "priority_id" => 2,
    "category" => 'Some Category',
    "state_id" => 1,
    "type" => "Some Type", 
    "customer" => $userID, 
    "article" => [
        "body" => $htmlBody,
        "type" => "note",
        "content_type" => "text/html",
    ],
    "tags" => "tag1,tag2,tag3", // or simply "tags" => "tag1"
]);
```

It might help someone in the future ...